# How to rollback offset in Kafka after getting error in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I a have a question about error processing in Logstash. 
In my case, i have the following cluster:

Kafka -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch

From what I understood, if Logstash reads the message from Kafka's topic and unable to write it into Elasticsearch, then it stops reading from the input (Kafka).
Does it mean, that the first message, which wasn't written into ES, will be lost, because Kafka's offset will be moved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The offset shouldn't be moved if the message has an error but that depends on the Logstash error handling. Any reason you're not using Confluent's Kafka Elasticsearch connector?

Comment: @cricket_007 , sorry for long response. I wish, i could use it, but that's not the decision i can make. At the moment, I just need to decide whether it is possible to do this error processing via logstash or not.

Comment: Logstash has DLQ features last time I checked, but so does Kafka 2.0